# Finding different elements between 2 vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, union

If I have 2 vectors of length 7 and 4 respectively (in R),

```
vec1 <- c(1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0)


vec2 <- c(1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```

I want to output a vector that shows the elements added to vec2 in order to create vec1

```
output <- c(1.0, 3.0, 4.0)
```

Comment: These are floating points.  So you won't get exact match

Comment: -9.0, -8.0, -4.0, 2.0, and -6.5 are in both vectors, so they won't appear in the output

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "additional elements"?  Do you mean "elements of `vec1` with index 36 to 42"?  No, because `-9.0` is not the 36th lements of `vec1`.  Do you mean "values in `vec1` that are not values in `vec2`?  No, because `-9.0` appears in both `vec1` and `vec2` and in your desired output.  So I don't know how you define "additional elements".

Answer (score 1):

`setdiff` seems to be working just fine:

```
> sort(unique(vec1))
 [1] -14.5 -13.5 -10.5 -10.0  -9.0  -8.5  -8.0  -7.5  -6.5  -5.5  -5.0  -4.5  -4.0  -3.5  -2.5   1.5   2.0
[18]   2.5   5.0   5.5   6.5   8.0   8.5  10.5
> sort(unique(vec2))
 [1] -14.5 -13.5 -10.5 -10.0  -9.0  -8.5  -8.0  -7.5  -6.5  -5.5  -5.0  -4.5  -4.0  -3.5  -2.5   2.0   2.5
[18]   5.5   6.5   8.0   8.5  10.5
```

Only 1.5 and 5.0 are in `vec1` and not in `vec2`

Comment: @Akrun, I just wanted to make the OP clear that what setdiff 'only' outputs is correct. We can probably close the question

Comment: Please let me know if the edit helps make the question a little more clear